# Can I change mindate message?

Tags: php, html, button

I am trying to change the min date message from "please select a value that is not earlier than 2018-10-02" to something like "please select a value that is not earlier than 02-10-2018".
[image]
Is it possible to change the date format of that message?

My code:

```
<input style="font-family: Arial;"
       class="date_input"
       type="date"
       id="dates" name="dates"
       min="<?php echo $today;?>"
       value="<?php echo $today;?>" />
```

Comment: show the code responsible for generating the err message

Comment: @treyBake it is a standard firefox message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`oninvalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninvalid):

```
<input style="font-family: Arial;"
       class="date_input"
       oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Some message about minimum date')
       type="date"
       id="dates" name="dates"
       min="<?php echo $today;?>"
       value="<?php echo $today;?>" />
```

Comment: inline js should be avoided as is bad practice that leads to hard-to maintain code

Comment: I don't think this single line is going to become a maintenance problem... this is also the shortest way to demonstrate the issue in an answer. @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Your somewhat nit picking here.

Comment: @Liam true, a single line won't but if OP doesn't know it's bad practice and uses it for every input ... it quickly adds up

Comment: It doesnt change the format of the error date... just ommits the date... any solution to that format changing?