# How to make custom validation error message?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, error-messaging

How can I make this kind of error message? I am building a login validation form.

[image: See example]

Comment: You could use a framework including tooltips, like Bootstrap...

Comment: Hey Napalm :) Have a read of [ask] and edit your question appropriately, normally including a [mcve] showing us what you have tried. Good luck :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change mindate message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605109/can-i-change-mindate-message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In addition:**

You can use `customValidity` api to create custom messages and will use the default tooltip provided by the browser.

**DOCS:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState

**Check bellow a simple example:**

https://jsbin.com/popazajawu/2/edit?html,js,console,output

**JS:**

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('invalid', function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("[CUSTOM MESSAGE] This field cannot be left blank")
  })

  input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this as simple as it

```
<input type= "text" name= "name" pattern= "[0-9]" required="required">
```

You can also set Length